# When/How Does My .NET Application Use Its App.Config File?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, app-config

I've never thought about it before; but I recently learned how I could modify the app.config file to add/remove trace listeners (for example, to redirect all of the Trace.WriteLine output to a text file).

But I don't quite understand how it works?  Can someone explain a bit?

I know the corresponding C# code to do the same as the config (in this example) - does that code get generated/executed before my application's entry point?

Comment: What aspect do you not understand? When the file loads? When trace listeners are added? What exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does that code get generated/executed before my application's entry point?

Think of a config file just as a standard text file. If your application code doesn't read and do anything with it, nothing will happen. So basically when you define some section in the app.config file, there is some code in your application (either in the BCL or custom) that at some moment will read, parse and interpret the values.

So, let's consider the example of trace listeners. When you try to trace something in your code, the underlying Trace class will use the config system to check the values you have defined in app.config. This config system parses the XML only once and stores it as singleton in memory to avoid the overhead everytime. So, it's only the first time you try to trace something that the config file is parsed and on subsequent calls the values are directly read from memory.

Answer (score 5):

The app.config filed is looked by your application every time you launch it.

You can store any of your settings in your app.config files, add or remove dynamically.

Here you go...

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="HospitalName" value="HML Hospital" />
    <add key="HospitalAddress" value="Madurai" />
    <add key="ServerName" value="SMSERVER" />
    <add key="DatabaseName" value="HospiCare" />
    <add key="DBUserID" value="sa" />    
    <add key="Theme" value ="Blue"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then you can alter the same as follows

using the namespace

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Read your config file as

```
string theme=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Theme");
```

and modify by using this

```
Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath));
configFile.AppSettings.Settings(KeyName).Value = KeyValue;
configFile.Save();
```

Accept and vote up if you find your anser

Answer (score 3):

As already others have explained. I would just like to explain a bit deeper i hope.

In .NET, your CLR creates a virtual boundary for your application. In other words, when your application is get hosted in CLR, it creates a virtual dimension for your application to play around. Its called AppDomain or Application Domain. 
This is the stage when your application reads App.Config file for any information. Because at times your App.Config will tell CLR what kinda run time assemblies it should look for ex: CLR 2.0 assemblies This is usually seen if your build apps in VS2010 for 2.0 or first create project for 4 and then change over to 2.0 target.